# Type casting from IEnumerable to ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, linq, casting, lambda

I want to get all the places which are active for bid. I tries this but I'm getting null.

```
testObservableList = testObservableList.Where(
                         x => x.IsActiveForBid) as ObservableCollection<Places>;
```

Comment: You good good answers to solve your problem. Be aware though that these solutions (technically) are not type casts. A type-cast is rarely possible between unrelated `IEnumerable` implementations. However, it's neither what you usually need. Creating a new sort of collection with the desired result is usually fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While an `ObservableCollection<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>` the opposite does not hold. Try a constructor:

```
new ObservableCollection<SometypeType>(
              testObservableList.Where(x => x.IsActiveForBid))
```

Answer (score 4):

try this.

```
testObservableList = 
new ObservableCollection(testObservableList.Where(x => x.IsActiveForBid));
```

This will make a shallow copy of the current IEnumerable and turn it in to a ObservableCollection

Comment: Error:
Using the generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Error:Using the generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ObservableCollection coll1 = new ObservableCollection(testObservableList.Where(x => x.IsActiveForBid);
```

I guess this will do it.